# Capture traffic for another computer on my home wifi network in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, packet-capture, promiscuous-mode

I am trying to do a packet capture for a computer in my home wifi network on my local machine. I am using ubuntu on my local machine.

These are the steps I have taken

```
sudo ifconfig <network_interface> down
sudo iwconfig <network_interface> mode monitor
sudo ifconfig <network_interface> up
```

However when I do `tcpdump host <target_machine_ip>` and try to run some curl command on the target machine I don't see any activity recorded on my local machine.

Additionally I have also tried running `ip link set eth1 promisc on` and then running the above exercise of running `curl command` on the target machine but I still don't see any activity on my local machine. Please advise what am I missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More info is available in the [help].

Comment: Thankyou will ask there